# How to get data from selected row? ASP.NET c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple html table that it's populated via server-side when I call the .aspx that contains the table, and I'm using this: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html to make the table selectable. Now my table is populated from data base and I can select different rows, everything good so far.

What I need to do is to get the data from the selected row via clicking a button and use the data I retrieved in the c# part. I haven't found any solution to this.

PS: I'm working with ASP.NET and c# (Visual Studio)

Thanks !

Comment: what button do you refer on clicking? and i suggest you to use SQL-Server for a better database source

Comment: The 'C# part' would be a server side piece of code that you need to send data to. So you have to SPOT or GET data off to the server side to do that. Do you understand the difference between server side (i.e. compiled C#) and client side (javascript)? What do you want to do with the data?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: did you mean POST instead of SPOT ?

Comment: Yes I know the difference. The only thing I want is to select a row and click a button and get the values to use them on server-side (c#). It would be values from asp to c#. I don't want to use ajax or something similar because I need to use c# and I have no time to learn something new at the moment.

Comment: I hear SPOT is coming in HTML 6. ;). If you want to asynchronously send the values to your server you need to learn ajax. If you want a button click to submit your values to the server and have it send back a page c# is fine.